# Raycast2D ray not follow object

Tags: unity, 2d, raycasting, gameobject

I have some Raycast2D problem. I want raycast follow the object like this:
[image]

But when I drag object somewhere the ray looklike this :
[image]

Here is my code where is my fault. Please help :(

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class RayCast : MonoBehaviour {
private float uzunluk = 5.0f;

void Start () 
{
}
void Update () {
    BoxCollider2D col2 = new BoxCollider2D();
    Vector2 dirs = new Vector2 (0, -1);

    Vector2 obj = new Vector2 (transform.position.x , (transform.position.y- 0.375f));
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (obj, dirs , uzunluk);
    Debug.DrawLine (obj, dirs , Color.cyan);
    if (hit.collider != col2)
    {
        Debug.Log("çarptı");
    } 
} 
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean? Where does the ray start, for instance? In the example you show, it seems quite clear that the ray **is** following the object. It draws *straight to it*.

Comment: I want always stay like photo-1. I mean I want when I drag object somewhere the ray follow the object and stay straight. But when I drag object the ray seems like photo -2  By the way ray starts under the object. IIf I change the dirs to `Vector.down` would it be clear?

Comment: So in other words, the raycast is suppose to represent a "looking forward" direction for the shape. If the shape rotates or moves, the raycast rotates or moves with it, and always displays the same "forward direction" at the same length. Is that correct?

Comment: I 'm beginner for Unity and I tried **raycast** first time. If this using like this this is totally useless. What kind of Ray this is. End point always stay , Start point always stay and Ray turn around between. I want start point (I mean from under the object) always stay under the object and end point change when I drag the object somewhere. But it didnt. :( And the example videos what I watch this is not like this. I want always stay straight but it look like photo-2 :(

Answer (score 1):

your Ray should be working fine you are just using the wrong debugging function. DrawLine draws a line in between 2 points not on that direction like the ray. Use Debug.DrawRay instead. Good Luck.